# ul li going outside of div

Tags: html, css

I created li inside a div. However, li are displayed outside div.

```css
.container>div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>There</li>
      <li>Where</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/zfvck809/

Comment: clearfix: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zfvck809/3/ (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).  More info about clearing floats: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to clear the float:left instruction :

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
   <div style="width:50%;border:1px solid red;">
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hi</li>
        <li>There</li>
        <li>Where</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS : 
.clearer {
 height:0;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked. could you please give me some insight about the solution.

Comment: When you are using float instruction on the element , it will be over others , so the element who encapsed it doesn't understand it. Clear instruction fix that :) please see documentation : 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 4):

You didn't clear the float, which means that the `<ul>`'s height is not effected by the `li` tags. There are many ways to clear floats, but this works well when you need to clear a float on a container:

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.container>div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul li {
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>There</li>
      <li>Where</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This stopped the display of the bullets, better but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to clear the floats given to the list items.

Try the following.

```css
 div ul{
        list-style-type:none;
    }


div ul:before,
div ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

div ul:after {
    clear:both;
}

    ul li{
       
        font-weight:700;
        float:left;
        width:48%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
    <div style="width:50%;border:1px solid red;">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>There</li>
            <li>Where</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the `before` for?

Comment: before and after are pseudo elements in css. Refer the following links for detailed description about them. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp . And in the above code, it's not really necessary to use before and after for 'ul'. You just need to clear the floats. You can remove "div ul:before,
div ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

div ul:after {
    clear:both;
}" and just add <br style="clear:both"> after the last element of <li>. That will fix the issue.

Comment: I know about psuedo elements, there is just no point in declaring the `before` in the above code.  It serves no purpose in a clear fix as you have used the after for that, you could just achieve the clear using div `ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}`

Comment: That's micro clearfix hack. Refer http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ for detailed information.

Comment: Your link was updated in august 2012 to the version in my above comment

Answer (score 0):

this will keep it inside the wrapper:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```